# uPnP port forwarding when PC is behind 2 routers or more?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, upnp

We have a web-server software that we need to install on various types of client PC. We're using uPnP port forwarding technique to allow remote access. Unfortunately, some client PCs are behind 2 routers or more, thus, port forwarding seems not feasible. Have you ever tried any solution that can solve this?

I know some online game can still works, so I think there is still solution. Highly appriciate and many thanks for any suggestion.

PS: Manually digging the router settings via router-control-panel (web-interface) shouldn't be a good idea, cause the clients are going to reset/replace router sometime, and we need port forwarding to be done automatically and programmatically.

Comment: I would strongly suggest changing your network architecture so that only one router is doing NAT.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : We can not lost the client just because they have their network oddly designed. (And it's a shame that skype, team viewer, etc.. can do that, but we can't)

Comment: You can't really compare server software to software that's not a server. Servers require Internet access.

Comment: All our effort is to make any PC that has ability to connect to internet become a server. Of course, to connect to this kinda server we have the specific client program.

Comment: Then your code should work even if the PC can only make an outbound connection to port 443, possibly through an HTTP proxy. The client should do the same, using a relay server if needed to reach the server. Otherwise, your effort is not yet complete.

Comment: Can you please clarify your idea in an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only feasible solution seems to be something that is called "TCP/UDP Hole Punching".
This technique is kind of cheating the network routers. The effect depends on the network, but it works with almost all normal networks & routers.